# Vue.js toggling expanding v-for component from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got an 'Album' component that is being used on a page. I am trying to create something whereby only one album can be toggled at a given time. So if an album is already open when clicking another it would close.

[image: Example of expanded album]

Component being mounted recursively in the 'parent' app.

```
<album v-for="(album, index) in albums"
  :key="index"
  @expand="setAlbumContainerHeight"
  @action="removeFromCollection"
  :albumDetails="album"
  page="collection">
</album>
```

The component itself.

```
<template>
    <div v-on:click="toggleExpand" ref="album" class="album">
        <img class="album-artwork" alt="album-artwork" :src="albumDetails.cover_url">
        <div ref="expandContent" class="expanded-content">
            <div class="left-block">
                <div class="title">{{ albumDetails.title }}</div>
                <div class="artist">{{ albumDetails.artist }}</div>

                <!-- Search page specific -->
                <div v-if="page === 'search'" class="info">{{ albumDetails.year }}<br> <span v-for="genre in albumDetails.genre"> {{ genre }}</span><br> {{ albumDetails.label }}</div>
                <!-- Collection page specific -->
                <div v-if="page === 'collection'" class="info">{{ albumDetails.year }}<br> <span v-for="genre in albumDetails.genres"> {{ genre.genre }}</span><br> {{ albumDetails.label }}</div>

                <!-- Search page specific -->
                <button v-if="page === 'search'" v-on:click.stop="addToCollection" class="add-collection">Add to collection</button>
                <!-- Collection page specific -->
                <button v-if="page === 'collection'" v-on:click.stop="removeFromCollection" class="add-collection">Remove from collection</button>
            </div>

            <div v-if="page === 'search'" class="right-block">
                <div class="a-side">
                    <p v-for="track in albumDetails.track_list_one" class="track">{{ track }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="b-side">
                    <p v-for="track in albumDetails.track_list_two" class="track">{{ track }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div v-if="page === 'collection'" class="right-block">
                <div class="a-side">
                    <p v-for="track in trackListOne" class="track">{{ track.track }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="b-side">
                    <p v-for="track in trackListTwo" class="track">{{ track.track }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img class="faded-album-artwork" alt="faded-album-artwork" :src="albumDetails.cover_url">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        name: 'Album',
        props: ['albumDetails', 'page'],

        data: function () {
            return {
                expanded: false,
                expandedContentHeight: 0,
                trackListOne: [],
                trackListTwo: []
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            if (this.albumDetails.tracks) {
                this.getTrackListOne(this.albumDetails.tracks);
                this.getTrackListTwo(this.albumDetails.tracks);
            }
        },

        methods: {
            toggleExpand() {
                if (!this.expanded) {
                    this.expanded = true;
                    this.$refs.expandContent.style.display = 'flex';
                    this.expandedContentHeight = this.$refs.expandContent.clientHeight;
                    let height = this.$refs.album.clientHeight + this.expandedContentHeight;
                    this.$emit('expand', height, event);
                } else {
                    this.expanded = false;
                    this.$refs.expandContent.style.display = 'none';
                    let height = 'initial';
                    this.$emit('expand', height, event);
                }
            },

            addToCollection() {
                this.$emit('action', this.albumDetails.cat_no);
            },

            removeFromCollection() {
                this.$emit('action', this.albumDetails.cat_no);
            },

            getTrackListOne(tracks) {
                let halfWayThough = Math.floor(tracks.length / 2);
                this.trackListOne = tracks.slice(0, halfWayThough);
            },

            getTrackListTwo(tracks) {
                let halfWayThough = Math.floor(tracks.length / 2);
                this.trackListTwo = tracks.slice(halfWayThough, tracks.length);
            },
        },
    }
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">
    @import './styles/album';
</style>
```

The component itself is storing its state with a simple 'expanded' data attribute. Currently this means that the component works nicely when a user is opening and closing each album, however, problems occur when they are opening several at a time. Due to absolute positioning I am manually having to set the height of the container. The aim is to have only one open at a time. I am having trouble thinking of a way to store and track what album is currently open - I'm also unsure how the parent can manage the stage each album / open and closing them where. Even if I know which album is open in the parent how can I trigger individual child components methods?

I've tried to be as clear as possible, please let me know if there's anything else I can make clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by recursive, as far as I can see you're not referencing the album component within itself recursively.

I'd go with this approach:
`expanded` is a property of your component.
On a click the component emits a `this.$emit('expand', albumID)`.
In your parent you listen for the `@expand` event and assign your `expandedAlbumID` to the event payload.
The last remaining piece of the puzzle is now to pass your `expanded` property like `:expanded="expandedAlbumID == album.id"`

Full working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o5p4p45m9

Comment: Sorry, I am probably using the wrong terminology there. Your solution certainly looks like it will do the trick on the working example you have provided. Thank you so much for taking the time to create an example, I'll take a look now and look at implementing something similar.

Comment: Thanks again for this, this is really annoying the way I am having to set the height of the container as this is making it a lot more complicated. Will continue developing and see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: I've just noticed one thing, this doesn't track if the user clicks the current open one (i.e to close it). Will need to build more logic into the way expanded is figured out.

Comment: @JakeFauvel in the `expandedEvent` method simply check if the new id equals the old one and if so set it to null. `if (e !== this.expandedAlbumID) this.expandedAlbumID = e; else this.expandedAlbumID = null;`

Comment: Yeah that was the route I went down. Works nicely. Correctly taking the expanded album now. Just need to sort the height. Shouldn't be tricky. Just needs to remove the previously expanded albums height.